# Chrome DevTools frame event timing

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, google-chrome, frame-rate

I'm using Chrome to isolate the bottle neck in the animations of an app.

It shows that frames are taking about 20+ms which is too slow. But when I expaned the frame to see what's going in, it shows me a jQuery call taking 20+ms, but the actual Recalculate Style event takes little more than 5ms.

How can I find out what is causing that delay? I can't see what the other 15ms are

The total event time:

[image: Chrome DevTools showing total time of jQuery function call]

The "Recalculate Style" event within the jQuery function

[image: Chrome DevTools showing split of timing for Recalculate Style event]

Stack before "Recalculate Style"

[image: Chrome DevTools showing stack for Recalculate Style event]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other nested events which make up that total 22.93ms should be listed just after the Recalculate Style event. For example, below you can see that there is a Function Call which takes a total of 9ms.  The purple number shows rendering time and the yellow number shows scripting time.

[image: Parent event]

If you dismiss the popup, you can see that every event which makes up that call is detailed below it.

[image: nested events]

Comment: Sorry I thought I'd commented on your answer. I added a screen shot to show the expanded event, and the only thing shown in side the function call is the recalculate styl event

Comment: Are you referring to the first screenshot?  If that's the case then there's no more detail to be had.  The code in question is at jquery-2.0.3-min.js at line 5.  However, since it's a minified version that won't be very helpful.  You can switch to the uncompressed version during development for easier debugging.

Comment: Ah that's a good point. Maybe that will help. Is it possible then that the jQuery function call itself just takes that long? I'll use the un-compresssed version to see what that function is

Comment: Yeah it certainly could.  And to keep things in perspective, "that long" (1/50th of a second) really isn't long in the grand scheme of things, only when you're dealing with micro-optimizations.  Maybe you can post the code in question and people can help you optimize it.  Also, if you don't want to switch between minified, non-minified versions, I believe 2.0.3 should have a source map available.  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

Comment: 60 fps means it needs to run in under 1/60th of a second though.

Comment: Sure, I understand why you need it to run that fast.  My point was just that, actually, 22ms is well within the normal performance envelope of JS so I'm not surprised at all you're seeing those numbers.  One thing you have to consider, though, is that you're micro-optimizing for a specific machine.  There's no guarantee that users' computers will be as fast as yours.  Personally, I would shift focus from micro-optimizations to larger architectural changes.  Perhaps do as many pre-calculations as possible before starting your animation?

Comment: I agree, I'm actually developing a Phonegap app for iPhone so my users devices are much slower than Chrome anyway. And you're right the more work I can do before the animation the better, but going back to the main point of the question, I just wanted to know what was going on in the frame. I'm hoping that using the non-minified version of jquery or using the source map, I'll be able to find out, and I'll post my findings when I do

Comment: So the real answer to my particular question I think is in your comment, "Are you referring to the first screenshot? If that's the case then there's no more detail to be had". Chrome tools can't go any deeper that that.